# Reading values from pipe in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, multiprocessing, pipe

I'm trying to write a program that finds a difference between two number but i need to calculate the numbers in different child process.

```
    #include <stdio.h>


    int squarePipe[2];
    int rectangleXPipe[2];
    int rectangleYPipe[2];

    int squareArea(int x){return x*x;}
    int rectangleArea(int x, int y){return x*y;}

    void main(){
       int pId,pId2 , sideOfSq, xOfRec, yOfRec, areaOfSq, areaOfRec ;
       int sentinel = 0;
       pipe(squarePipe);
       pipe(rectangleXPipe);
       pipe(rectangleYPipe);    

pId = fork();       

if( pId == 0 ){
  read( squarePipe[0],sideOfSq,sizeof(int) );
  write( squarePipe[1], squareArea(sideOfSq),sizeof(int) );
}
else{
    pId2 = fork();  
    if( pId2 == 0 ){
    read( rectangleXPipe[0], xOfRec, sizeof(int) );
    read( rectangleYPipe[0], yOfRec, sizeof(int) );
    write( rectangleXPipe[1], rectangleArea(xOfRec,yOfRec),sizeof(int) );

    }
    else{
       printf("Enter the side of square\n");
       scanf("%d",&sideOfSq);
       write( squarePipe[1], sideOfSq,sizeof(int));

       printf("Enter the x sides of rectangle\n");
       scanf("%d",&xOfRec);
       printf("Enter the y sides of rectangle\n");
       scanf("%d",&yOfRec);     //bilgilerin alınması 

       write( rectangleXPipe[1], xOfRec,sizeof(int));
       write( rectangleYPipe[1], yOfRec,sizeof(int));

       read( rectangleXPipe[0], areaOfRec, sizeof(int) );
       read( squarePipe[0],areaOfSq,sizeof(int) );


       printf("difference = %d", areaOfSq-areaOfRec);
    }
}
}
```

I'm stuck here. I think one of those pipes does not respond but I could not figure it out.

Comment: How about closing the pipes after they have been used?

Comment: I just tried it did not work.

Comment: You can use `void main()` on a Windows machine (regrettably); you cannot use `void main()` on Unix generally and Linux specifically.  It is simply an incorrect way of writing `main()`; it always returns an `int` on Unix/Linux.  And if GCC isn't complaining about it, you aren't using enough warning options.  At a minimum, you should use `-Wall`; preferably use at least `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`; I use fussier options than those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read calls are broken — and the compiler should be complaining.  It isn't presumably because you don't have enough headers included or enough compiler warning options enabled.

When I compile your code, I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c borked.c
borked.c:8:9: error: no previous prototype for ‘squareArea’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
     int squareArea(int x){return x*x;}
         ^
borked.c:9:9: error: no previous prototype for ‘rectangleArea’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
     int rectangleArea(int x, int y){return x*y;}
         ^
borked.c:11:10: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
     void main(){
          ^
borked.c:11:10: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
borked.c: In function ‘main’:
borked.c:11:10: error: old-style function definition [-Werror=old-style-definition]
borked.c:14:8: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pipe’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
        pipe(squarePipe);
        ^
borked.c:18:1: error: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 pId = fork();       
 ^
borked.c:21:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘read’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   read( squarePipe[0],sideOfSq,sizeof(int) );
   ^
borked.c:22:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘write’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   write( squarePipe[1], squareArea(sideOfSq),sizeof(int) );
   ^
borked.c:13:12: error: unused variable ‘sentinel’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
        int sentinel = 0;
            ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The 'previous prototype' warnings are valid but I'd not complain if your code omitted them.  The other warnings are more serious, and the lack of prototype for `read` and `write` means you are hindering yourself.

Fixing up the basic problems by various devious means and including `<unistd.h>` gives different warnings.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int squarePipe[2];
int rectangleXPipe[2];
int rectangleYPipe[2];

static inline int squareArea(int x) { return x * x; }

static inline int rectangleArea(int x, int y) { return x * y; }

int main(void)
{
    int pId, pId2, sideOfSq, xOfRec, yOfRec, areaOfSq, areaOfRec;
    int sentinel = 0;
    pipe(squarePipe);
    pipe(rectangleXPipe);
    pipe(rectangleYPipe);

    pId = fork();

    if (pId == 0)
    {
        read( squarePipe[0], sideOfSq, sizeof(int) );
        write( squarePipe[1], squareArea(sideOfSq), sizeof(int) );
    }
    else
    {
        pId2 = fork();
        if (pId2 == 0)
        {
            read( rectangleXPipe[0], xOfRec, sizeof(int) );
            read( rectangleYPipe[0], yOfRec, sizeof(int) );
            write( rectangleXPipe[1], rectangleArea(xOfRec, yOfRec), sizeof(int) );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter the side of square\n");
            scanf("%d", &sideOfSq);
            write( squarePipe[1], sideOfSq, sizeof(int));

            printf("Enter the x sides of rectangle\n");
            scanf("%d", &xOfRec);
            printf("Enter the y sides of rectangle\n");
            scanf("%d", &yOfRec); // bilgilerin alınması

            write( rectangleXPipe[1], xOfRec, sizeof(int));
            write( rectangleYPipe[1], yOfRec, sizeof(int));

            read( rectangleXPipe[0], areaOfRec, sizeof(int) );
            read( squarePipe[0], areaOfSq, sizeof(int) );


            printf("difference = %d", areaOfSq - areaOfRec);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation warnings

Same command line as before.

```
borked.c: In function ‘main’:
borked.c:24:9: error: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
         read( squarePipe[0], sideOfSq, sizeof(int) );
         ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:466:10: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  read(int, void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(read);
          ^
borked.c:25:9: error: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
         write( squarePipe[1], squareArea(sideOfSq), sizeof(int) );
         ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:490:10: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  write(int, const void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(write);
          ^
borked.c:32:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             read( rectangleXPipe[0], xOfRec, sizeof(int) );
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:466:10: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  read(int, void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(read);
          ^
borked.c:33:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             read( rectangleYPipe[0], yOfRec, sizeof(int) );
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:466:10: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  read(int, void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(read);
          ^
borked.c:34:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             write( rectangleXPipe[1], rectangleArea(xOfRec, yOfRec), sizeof(int) );
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:490:10: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  write(int, const void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(write);
          ^
borked.c:40:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             write( squarePipe[1], sideOfSq, sizeof(int));
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:490:10: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  write(int, const void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(write);
          ^
borked.c:47:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             write( rectangleXPipe[1], xOfRec, sizeof(int));
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:490:10: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  write(int, const void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(write);
          ^
borked.c:48:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             write( rectangleYPipe[1], yOfRec, sizeof(int));
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:490:10: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  write(int, const void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(write);
          ^
borked.c:50:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             read( rectangleXPipe[0], areaOfRec, sizeof(int) );
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:466:10: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  read(int, void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(read);
          ^
borked.c:51:13: error: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
             read( squarePipe[0], areaOfSq, sizeof(int) );
             ^
In file included from borked.c:2:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:466:10: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ssize_t  read(int, void *, size_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(read);
          ^
borked.c:15:9: error: unused variable ‘sentinel’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int sentinel = 0;
         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

This tells you pretty much line by line where there are problems.  Go fix!